# Building MEF Parts in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, mef

I am building a application with plugins based on MEF. When my plugin is in C#, things are clear. Plugins use Export attributes with metadata to export interfaces, and my application consumes them nicely.

When my plugin needs to be in Powershell, it is not very clear how things will work.

1. Can I create a class in Powershell with the same MEF Export Attributes
   to export interfaces my plugin/part will implement.
2. And prior to class support (in Powershell 5), how
   would I handle this.
3. Which MEF Catalog (AssemblyCatalog,DirectoryCatalog) can I use for discovery from Powershell script.

Thank you.